# Advanced access for `write` on res.partner

Tags: python, security, acl, odoo, odoo-10

Is data that was supplied to `write()` with parameter (`vals`) accessible from within method `check_access_rights`?

I inherited from `res.partner` and overriden method `check_access_rights` with intent to allow a user with no write rights on `res.partner` to update `child_ids` (of that partner) if that child was created by that user (create_uid = user.id) . I hope to be able to implement somewhere (in methods `write` or `check_access_rights`) this pseudo-code:

```
if `the user belongs to a group "GroupX"` and `user tries to only update field "child_ids" with records that are created by that user`
    then `allow this write operation on res.partner`
    else `raise AccessError`
```

Comment: What about overriding `write()` of `res.partner` directly and raising a warning if provided child_ids entries can't be written by the writing user?

Comment: Hello @CZoellner this worked! Please add as an answer :).

Comment: just post your final code as the answer. I just gave an advice ;-)

Comment: @CZoellner posted :). Anyway Thank you very much for advice:).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To let user (from "Group X") modify res.partner objects that where created by him and let modify child_ids on res.partner objects that where created by anyone:

first create a group "Group X" with rights: a) r,w,c,u on res.partner ; b) r,w,c on ir.property .

Then create a class that inherits from res.partner and override method `write`.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class InheritedResPartner(models.Model):
    """Description""" 
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    @api.multi
    def write(self, vals):
        is_in_group = 'Group X' in map(lambda x: x.name, self.env.user.groups_id)
        if is_in_group:
            operation = 'write'
            owns_record = self.create_uid == self.env.user

            if owns_record:
                True
            else:
                allowed = True

                # Do all checks further and set `allowed` to either True or False 
                ...<omitted intentionaly> put your logic here
                #

                if not allowed:
                    raise AccessError(_('The requested operation cannot be completed due to security restrictions. Please contact your system administrator.\n\n(Document type: %s, Operation: %s)') % (self._description, operation))
        return super(InheritedResPartner, self).write(vals)
```

Note: we give full rights on res.partner but we will override write method and raise AccessError if unwanted action detected.